# Juniper ERX 310 traffic not going more than 710 mbps?

Tags: router, juniper, pppoe

We have a Juniper ERX 310 configured as B-ras, as per specifications of the router, we should be able to terminate 8000 PPP sessions, but we notice that traffic on the router interface not going more than 710 Mbps.

Below is the interface configuration:

```
interface gigabitEthernet 2/0  
ip block-multicast-sources  
ip address x.x.x.x/x  
no ip proxy-arp
```

There is no limitation on the interface, so is it hardware limitation?

Below are the router modules:

```
SRP310-10G
 GE-2 I/O
```

Comment: How did you measure the traffic going on the interface, what protocols did you use? Did you use some traffic generator?

Comment: I check the interface from cli

Comment: Can you post the output of "show hardware" and "show version"?  (all of it)

Comment: How large are the packets? Remember that throughput depends on packet size (due to overhead) - for small (64-byte) packets, the maximum rate in bits per second on a gigabit link is less than 800Mbps.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score -4):

"Gigabit Ethernet" = 1024 Mbps total maximum.

After Ethernet & Protocol overhead, you're going to cap out at ~850 Mbps under the most ideal circumstances.

Source: Network Engineer for a Fortune 50 who works extensively with Juniper gear.

Comment: He is getting well under 850Mbps, assuming your other statements are accurate.  FYI, GigabitEthernet is 1000Mbps because data transfer is [measured in SI units](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3628/iec-or-si-units-binary-prefixes-used-for-network-measurement).  Overall, I don't understand how this answers the question yet.